# How to get rid of old activities from showing up to the user?

Tags: android

I made an app with a package name like

com.app.yesterday.MyActivity

I started a new project with a new package name

com.app.today.MyActivity.

Now when the most recent app is launched, the device is presenting the user with a selection screen for the right activity:

=======================================

Select an action:

com.app.yesterday.MyActivity

com.app.today.MyActivity

=======================================

What I would like is for this not to show at all because "yesterday" is irrelevant and "today" should be automatically launched? How can I do this? I can't the app in my Manage Applications section because the debugger uninstall it.

Comment: Why the down mark with no comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find it in the manage application list, try renaming the package again, uninstall it, and then change the package name again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably uninstall the associate .apk. The reason why I couldn't find it is because I didn't fine a name in the manifest.xml. So it will default to the fully qualified package name which I wasn't really looking for.